Acquiring an access token using REST API on a ARC Connected VM
I'm wanting to connect a On-Prem VM to Azure KeyVault. I have installed the Azure Arc Agent successfully and can see the VM under ARC Machines in Azure.
However when I go to request the API token as per here I receive the following error..
PS C:\Users\tasks> Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{Metadata='True'} -UseBasicParsing
Invoke-WebRequest : 
    
        Runtime Error
        
        
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:pointer; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        
    
    
            Server Error in '/' Application.
             Runtime Error 
            
             Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, 
however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
            
            Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the 
current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.

I think the error is related to either IDENTITY_ENDPOINT or the URL.
Any suggestions on how I request a TOKEN from a ARC connected VM?
Thanks in Advanced.
Shane
Here is the Code from the above site..
$apiVersion = "2020-06-01"
$resource = "https://management.azure.com/"
$endpoint = "{0}?resource={1}&api-version={2}" -f $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT,$resource,$apiVersion
$secretFile = ""
try
{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{Metadata='True'} -UseBasicParsing
}
catch
{
    $wwwAuthHeader = $_.Exception.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"]
    if ($wwwAuthHeader -match "Basic realm=.+")
    {
        $secretFile = ($wwwAuthHeader -split "Basic realm=")[1]
    }
}
Write-Host "Secret file path: " $secretFile`n
$secret = cat -Raw $secretFile
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{Metadata='True'; Authorization="Basic $secret"} -UseBasicParsing
if ($response)
{
    $token = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $response.Content).access_token
    Write-Host "Access token: " $token
}



It looks like you're running commands individually. It's supposed to be run as a .ps1 script. You should also check that the required environment variable is set o  your machine. Type $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT and just hit enter. You should get some value back, like http://localhost:12345/something

Thanks @Architect Jamie I've run it as a ps1 script with the same result. I've also checked the environment variables and it's not there. I read that it should be set under identities in the portal but there is no identity available. any idea how it's supposed to be set? TIA!

You probably just need to enable managed identity for the machine. If you select the "VM" in the Portal, you should see an Identity settings section. This is where you enable it. Select system-managed for simplicity. Once you've applied the settings, Azure should automatically populate the necessary environment variables on the machine. You may need to restart it though. Also, you will now be able to assign KeyVault permissions to the machine in IAM - The list of principals you can grant permissions to should contain the VM name.

Thanks, I think I have an issue with the ARC connection as I cannot see the ARC connected VM in my VM's in Azure. If I look at the ARC connection I can see that it succeeded, so I dunno! lol

Have you checked Portal -> Azure ARC -> Servers?

yep, I can see it in there but not in Virtual Machines. I was also able to install an extension with no issue.

I've posted an answer for you.

[Derived from comments on question]
To obtain a token for an Azure Arc-enabled server (physical or virtual) you need to enable Managed Identity on the server.
Arc-enabled servers do not display in the Virtual Machines resource category in the Portal. You will be able to see a list of servers in:
Portal -> Azure Arc -> Servers.

Click on the server you want to enable Managed Identity on
Click on Identity in the Settings section
Toggle System assigned managed identity to on

Once you apply the settings, after a few moments, an identity will be sent to the Arc agent running on the server and the necessary environment variables will be set accordingly. You can then use the script to obtain an access token for authorisation on other Azure resources.
